# Add jar file But error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper

Tags: android, json, spring, jackson

I have a project for Spring android basic auth.

The Project for auth is:- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-android-samples/tree/master/spring-android-basic-auth

This in file Go-to :- `.....\Downloads\spring-android-samples-master\spring-android-basic-auth\client`

The Jar File i added is:

```
spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.0.1.jar
```

The error occurs in :

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
```

But steel i get error of java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.

Please help me to solve this issue.

I am new to android please help to solve this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am not sure how this works in android but the error states `.NoClassDefFoundError` which occurs when your class is not available at the classpath. Please check the configurations and the class path. The error is here only.

Comment: The jar what i added is correct  or  it needs any other jar file,  I have select the checkbox in java build path for all jar files then what other i should check.   please reply. @ –  Ekansh Rastogi

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem, because I'm having the very same problem right now?

Comment: "The Jar File i added is: " Where did you add these JAR files? Be sure they are in the `app/libs` subdirectory in your project.